# Unable to use the Golang otel http client to propagate B3 headers to downstream service

Tags: trace, distributed, distributed-tracing, otel

I'm trying to use the otel packages to do tracing header (b3) propagation. Unfortunately I'm unable to get this to work. For the purposes of explaining, I have created a project on github which illustrates my problem: https://github.com/rogierlommers/otel-b3-header-propagation.

For a schematic view, please see image below:

[image]

My expectations are that all incoming headers (passed in by cURL command) are propagated to the downstream service, by using the otel http wrapper [here](https://github.com/rogierlommers/otel-b3-header-propagation/blob/main/api/backend/backend.go#L17). Unfortunately this doesn't happen and I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, turns out that I needed to provide more than only the `X-B3-TraceId`-header. For future reference I'll keep this post and the linked github repo ([here](https://github.com/rogierlommers/otel-b3-header-propagation)).